# SSO SharePoint 2013 for 2 domains

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, authentication, membership-provider

Hi We are building apps with sharepoint 2013. Currently we have them setup as two web applications with two separate domain names -

- Wep App 1 - www.webapp1.com
- Web App 2 - www.webapp2.com

---

We also have ASP.net membership role provider database which we use for authentication. right now we want to implement Single Sign On for both the Web App. If i Authenticate with one web app and i try to navigate to the other web app i should **not** be asked to re-authenticate again.

How can i achieve this. i cannot use ADFS as we maintain a separate database with all the user info as a part of asp.net membership role provider. Can someone guide me on how this can be achieved.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: should be asked to re-authenticate again oR shldnot be ?

Comment: single sign on - should not ask to re-authenticate.

Comment: Comon guys no update ...?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Trusted Identity Provider (STS,  security token service) with your own membership inside. Few links to dig deeper:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/life_of_a_sharepoint_consultant/archive/2010/12/01/writing-your-own-trusted-identity-provider-for-sp2010-1.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955607%28v=office.14%29.aspx